# system of linear congruences when moduli are not coprime

Tags: discrete-mathematics, congruences

$\begin{cases}x\equiv 1 \pmod{3}\\
x\equiv 2 \pmod{5}\\
x\equiv 3 \pmod{7}\\
x\equiv 4 \pmod{9}\\
x\equiv 5 \pmod{11}\end{cases}$

I am supposed to solve the system using the Chinese remainder theorem but $(3,5,7,9,11)\neq 1$ 
How can I transform the system so that I will be able to use the theorem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Observe that $\displaystyle x\equiv4\pmod 9\implies x\equiv4\pmod3\equiv1$

Now, we can safely apply [C.R.T](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/blue/chinese.shtml) on $$\begin{cases}
x\equiv 2 \pmod5\\
x\equiv 3 \pmod7\\
x\equiv 4 \pmod9\\
x\equiv 5 \pmod{11}\end{cases}$$ as $5,7,9,11$ are pairwise relatively prime

Comment: Of course!:) I should have notice that. Thank you

Comment: @HeidiE, observe that if it were $x\equiv0\pmod3$ or $x\equiv2\pmod3$, we would have no solution of the system

Answer (score 0):

Solving the first two equations simultaneously you get X = 7(mod 15).

Solving the third and fourth simultaneously you get X = 31(mod 63).

Solving these two results simultaneously you get X = 157(mod 315).

Solving this result with the fifth equation simultaneously,

you get the final answer X = 1732(mod 3465).